# How to determine if a matrix is diagonizable?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Consider the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}3 &0\\ 0& 3\end{bmatrix}$. To determine whether it can be diagonalised, I have found eigvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ which are both $= 3$, but then I get an eigvec of $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$. The solution says it's diagonalisable but I don't see how that is true because the eigvec can't be a 0 eigvec.

---

**edit** the original question the $A$ matrix was accidentally $A = \begin{bmatrix}3 &0\\ 3& 0\end{bmatrix}$ which gave the answer below which could also be useful if you are new to learning this.

Comment: check your computation here: your eigenvalues should be 0 and 3

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. A=[3 0 ; 0 3]

Comment: So since this is a scalar multiple (3) of the identity matrix, the eigenvalues will be $\lambda_1 = 3, \lambda_2 = 3$. And your eigenvectors will just be $[0,1]$ and $[1,0]$, respectively.

Comment: Thanks! how do you get [0,1] and [1,0] for eigvecs?

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of a Null Space?

Comment: Hi Gabrielle and welcome to the site. Please learn some math typesetting with mathjax which will help people help you. Also please double check your questions before  you post them to avoid someone answering the wrong question.

Comment: Don't you know that a diagonal matrix is diagonizable ?

Answer (score 1):

$x^2-3x=0$ is the characteristic polynomial of $\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\3&0 \end{bmatrix}$ yielding the roots $x=0,3$.

To find the eigenvectors, we find the null space of the two matrices formed by subtracting eigenvalues from the diagonal entries:
$\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\3&0 \end{bmatrix}$ with null space spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.

and the second matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\3&-3 \end{bmatrix}$, with nullspace spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Yielding two linearily independent eigenvectors and telling you that your matrix is indeed diagonalizable.

Comment: Im upvoting your question as it answered the original question perfectly, not that it answers the intended **edited** question. You could not help that the questioner was not careful when writing the original.